# Postfix: User with aliases has a mailbox, with filename where all aliases are listed

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot

I have a postfix server running on my CentOS 7 machine.

I managed to configure the postfix server to use my LDAP server to retrieve accounts and it works fine, emails are received and saved to a mailbox file.

I use Dovecot as an IMAP server. They work together nicely for all users, except for the ones that have aliases.

The problem is that Dovecot is looking for the mailbox file with the user's `maildrop` attribute (which is of course unique). However, the mailbox file created by Postfix is a list of all `mail` attributes (which are the list of aliases).

For example, let's suppose a user with `cn=user, maildrop=user, mail=user, mail=alias`.

In this case, the mailbox file created by Postfix will be called `user,alias`, while Dovecot will look for a file called `user`.

---

Now of course, I could start to find out how to make Dovecot look for a file called `user,alias`, but this would mean that every time a new alias is added to an account, all of the emails will not be recallable until that alias is deleted.

So what I need help with is to configure Postfix to call the mailbox file `user`, even when `mail=user` has multiple aliases.

Relevant part of `main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mail.ropi.dev, ropi.dev
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/mail_default
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-accounts.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 3000
virtual_uid_maps = static:3000
virtual_gid_maps = static:3000
virtual_transport = virtual
```

`ldap-accounts.cf`:

```
# ...
query_filter = (&(objectClass=mailUser)(maildrop=%u))
result_attribute = mail

version = 3
```

`ldap-aliases.cf`:

```
# ...
query_filter = (&(objectClass=mailUser)(mail=%u))
result_attribute = maildrop

version = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized my mistake, I needed to modify `ldap-accounts.cf` in a way that it returns not the aliases (`mail`), but the "main" email address, which is in the `maildrop` attribute.